# Hyperledger fabric NodeOUs not activated. Cannot tell apart identities

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I try to approve a chaincode package it throws a timeout error. 
The peer logs show the following warnings. Even though I have config.yaml file in the MSP directory with NodeOUs enable to true, it says NodeOus not activated. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?  I use hyperledger fabric 2.0 binaries. 
`identity 0 does not satisfy principal: The identity is not a [PEER] under this MSP [org1MSP]: NodeOUs not activated. Cannot tell apart identities.`

`WARN 1012b Peer {"CN":"peer2-org1","Issuer-CN":"rca-org1.inuit.local","Issuer-L-ST-C":"[RM]-[]-[IT]","Issuer-OU":["fabric"],"L-ST-C":"[]-[]-[US]","MSP":"org1MSP","OU":["peer"]} isn't eligible for channel twoorgschannel : implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied`

Answer (score 1):

This is my fault not to include policy definitions in the orderer system channel. So even  though I have enabled NodeOUs in MSPs and defined policies in configtx.yaml, I didn't include channel policies in the orderersystemchannel. So it throws the error mentioned in the question above.